# MVC js Unexpected token in JSON when string contains /n /r

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code

on my action

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var statements = logicManager.GetDefaultStatements();
    var langs = logicManager.GetLanguagesList();
    ViewBag.LangList = langs;
    ViewBag.StatementList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(statements);
    return View();
}
```

on my View I have the following

```
@{
    var langList = (List<DataModels.LanguageModel>)ViewBag.LangList;
    var statementList = ViewBag.StatementList;
}
```

and at the buttom of my view I have the following

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var statementsData = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(statementList)');
        Statement.init(statementsData);
    });
</script>
```

when my page is loading I get an error:

> "Unexpected token in JSON at position ....  "

it appears due to the /r or /n inside my statementList object properties.

Any way to fix that without losing the line breaks?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check the view source of the page and see what is being passed to the `JSON.parse` method. your code looks fine

Comment: there was a comment here that helped me half way
anyway due to the deleted comment inspiration I did this and it's working  

  'var statementsData = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(statementList)));'